# Fill and print - Two Dimensional Arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to learn c++, I started working with Two Dimensional Arrays.
I decided to begin with simple - fill and print functions. I have done it before with a one-dimensional array, but I have a little problem with it now. I can see "|35|error: cannot convert 'int (*)[10]' to 'int**'|" error
Thats my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void Fill(int ** T, int x, int y){
srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i<y; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<x; j++){
            T[i][j] = rand()%100;
        }
    }
}

void Print(int ** T, int x, int y){
    for(int j = 0; j<y; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i<x; i++){
            cout<<T[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}



int main()
{

int T[10][10];
Fill(T, 10, 10);
Print(T, 10, 10);


}
```

What did i wrong ? Did I give arguments correctly ?

Comment: You should start with [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of C style arrays. Your code looks like legacy code. That's not how you should start learning C++. C++ arrays solve your problem.

Comment: A 2D array does not translate to a pointer to a pointer as you have no doubt noticed. `int T[10][10]` converts to `int (*)[10]`. You need to provide all but the first dimension of the array so that the compiler can generate the correct indexing math for you, making it extremely hard to pass a 2D array around unless you know ahead of time what those fixed dimensions are. My usual work around is to use 1D arrays and perform all of the indexing math myself. I make this easier with a wrapper class that contains the array and provides methods to do the correct indexing.

Comment: [Here is a simple example based around a `std::vector`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301)

Comment: @user4581301: Interestingly your observation "it is extremely hard to pass a 2D array around unless you know ahead of time what those fixed dimensions are" applies equally to the recommendation others are making of `std::array`.  For plain old legacy arrays, non-type template parameters can save you from knowing the fixed dimensions (as long as they are fixed at compile-time the compiler will automatically infer template arguments)

Answer (score 0):

You should start with [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of C style arrays. Your code looks like legacy code. That's not how you should start learning C++. C++ arrays solve your problem.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

using MyArray = std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10>;

void Fill(MyArray &T){
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(auto &row : T){
        for(auto &el : row){
            el = rand()%100;
        }
    }
}

void Print(const MyArray &T){
    for(auto &row : T){
        for(auto &el : row){
            cout<<el<<" ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    MyArray T;
    Fill(T);
    Print(T);
}
```

Comment: is <ctime> needed?

Comment: @ChandraPrakashDixit Yes, for `time`.

Comment: Note that `using MyArray = int[10][10];` would have made OP's legacy array code look just as nice -- there's not actually any advantage to `std::array` here, the type alias is doing all the heavy lifting.

Comment: Also, `<ctime>` only works here because of the (ill-advised) `using namespace std;`  In general `#include <time.h>` will give you a global function `time()` and `#include <ctime>` will give you `std::time()`.  They aren't guaranteed to give the other name as well, although they can; assuming that they do leads to non-portable code.

Comment: @ThomasSablik actually using `std::random_device` and alike instead of `rand` might be better (more C++, less C) but I might be being picky here.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer:

```
int T[10][10];
```

is a group of contiguous ints with no pointers involved, whereas

```
int **
```

should point on an `int *`. That's the reason why you cannot convert `T` to an `int **`

When you write `T[i][j]` you are doing pointer arithmetic using a pointer of type `int (*p)[10]` then a pointer of type `int *p`. Again no pointer is stored into `T`. Here is a concrete example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t COLUMN_SIZE>
int
get_Tij(int T[][COLUMN_SIZE], int i, int j)
{
  // A pointer on an array of COLUMN_SIZE ints
  int(*p)[COLUMN_SIZE] = T;

  // Select row i, the stride is COLUMN_SIZE*sizeof(int)
  int* p_i = p[i];

  // Select column j, the stride is sizeof(int)
  int p_ij = p_i[j];

  return p_ij;
}

int
main()
{
  int T[2][3] = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}};

  std::cout << "\n" << get_Tij(T, 0, 0);
  std::cout << "\n" << get_Tij(T, 0, 1);
  std::cout << "\n" << get_Tij(T, 1, 0);

  std::cout << "\n" << T[0][0];
  std::cout << "\n" << T[0][1];
  std::cout << "\n" << T[1][0];
}
```

which prints

> ```
> 0
> 1
> 3
> 0
> 1
> 3
> ```

---

If you want to learn C++, as already said in comment/other answers, you should use `std::array` (for static size vectors) or `std::vector` (for dynamic size vectors)